# passing 0 through form GET and its null, yet intval(0) is 0

Tags: php

`HTML`:

```
echo "<form action='procSS.php' method='get'>\n";
echo "<button style='color:black;' type='submit' name='start' value='" . $data[0]\ . "'> start </button>";

echo "<button style='color:black;' type='submit' name='stop' value='" . $data[0] . \"'> stop </button>";
echo "</form>";
```

procSS.php

```
<?php

$server_conn = stream_socket_client("tcp://127.0.0.1:9000", $errno, $errmsg);

echo intval(0);

if($_GET['start'] == null || $_GET['stop'] == null) {
    echo "its null my dude";
}
if(!empty($_GET['start'])) {
    fwrite($server_conn, "Start ".$_GET['start']."");
    echo "Start ".$GET_['start'];
    fclose($server_conn);
} elseif(!empty($_GET['stop'])) {
    fwrite($server_conn, "Stop ".$_GET['stop']."");
    echo "Stop ".$_GET['stop'];
    fclose($server_conn);
}  elseif(!empty($_GET['reset'])) {
    fwrite($server_conn, "Restart ".$_GET['reset']."");
    fclose($server_conn);
} else {
    echo "???";
}

?>
```

Okay so this is the url -> `http://localhost/procSS.php?stop=0` and it clearly sends 0. the output on the php page is: `0its null my dude???`. So I did intval(0) which it returns 0. Next we see that $_GET['stop'] is null even though it passes 0. Why is this and how can I fix it? intval(0) is 0, but passing 0 through get is null

Answer (score 0):

because it both are false 0 is false as well as null is also false when used for condition

use strict type checking(===) like this 0 === null

Comment: it's a integer only it's typecasted when used in a boolean expression..

Comment: If its an integer how come i cannot do echo "$_GET['stop'];". It is null here as well and this is not a boolean expression

Comment: are you taking about this elseif(!empty($_GET['stop'])) {? if it is, 0 is considered empty so elseif will not pass..

Comment: Ok so 0 is passed as seen in the url -> http://localhost/procSS.php?stop=0 if all you have on the page is echo "$_GET['stop']" nothing prints because it is null.

Comment: if there is nothing in the page except echo $_GET['stop'] it will print 0 also remove the "(double quotes) around $_GET['stop'] ..

Comment: if you want to "$_GET['stop']" use like this "{$_GET['stop']}" or store it in a varible and use it